# Launch default browser spotlight shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, safari, spotlight, google-chrome, web-browsing

I often switch my default browser between Safari and Chrome. I would like to create a shortcut that will launch the default browser, whatever that may be. This way I don't have to remember what my default browser is and switch between typing "Chr" or "Saf" in spotlight. I would like to type the same word such as "Browser".

What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make a little AppleScript that does this:

```
on GetDefaultWebBrowser()
    set _scpt to "export VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=yes; " & "perl -MMac::InternetConfig -le " & "'print +(GetICHelper \"http\")[1]'"
    return (do shell script _scpt)
end GetDefaultWebBrowser
do shell script "open -a \"" & GetDefaultWebBrowser() & "\""
```

Replace the URL (in quotes) with your homepage.
The rest of the code serves to figure out what your default browser is, and make it the active application. That part lifted from a Daring Fireball [article](http://daringfireball.net/2009/01/applescripts_targetting_safari_or_webkit).

Save it as an app called Browser and put it somewhere. Once Spotlight indexes it, you can type Browser in and hit enter. This will open the URL in your default browser.

**Directions:**

Open AppleScript Editor from your Applications/Utilities folder (if you have older than 10.6, it will be Script Editor in your Applications folder). Paste that line in. Go to File-> Save As. Set the File Format: menu to Application. Choose a location and save.

Comment: Web addresses as home pages are *so* 90s ^^; (though some good landing pages nowadays do exist) I wish there would be something like `about:home` which would translate to the whatever homepage in the whatever browser.

Comment: @koiyu I wanted to use `about:blank` (fast), but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: @Nathan `open location "http://"` opens `about:blank` (at least with Chrome). But blank isn't quite the same as home page.

Comment: @koiyu Doesn't work for Safari. Fills in http://localhost/. True, it isn't a homepage, but it tends to be faster.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an OS X newbie. Could you please elaborate as to how I would create and save this file?

Comment: @Senseful Updated

Comment: After using this method for a while, I see two problems: (1) launching the app when Chrome is the default browser always causes Chrome to start up with two tabs (blank tab and google). (2) It doesn't set focus on the browser, instead it causes Finder to remain the focused app.

Comment: @Senseful: Updated to activate the browser.

Comment: @Nathan: I just figured out the perfect solution. Please delete your first and last lines, then add the following line at the end: `do shell script "open -a \"" & GetDefaultWebBrowser() & "\""`

Comment: @Senseful Nice. Changed it.

Answer (score 3):

This may be too low tech of a solution for you but what about creating a web shortcut file (naming it "Browser") to say, your homepage, and then either putting that shortcut in your dock (and accessing it from there), or searching for that file via spotlight - when clicked the default browser would open.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: Nathan edited his answer after I posted this, so mine seemed completely pointless. So I added the reopen verb — it's a bit tidier way to make sure that the browser doesn't open up with no windows.*

*Also, you don't have to save Applescripts as .app to run them from Spotlight — .applescript and .scpt also work*

```
set a to do shell script "export VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=yes; perl -MMac::InternetConfig -le 'print +(GetICHelper \"http\")[1]'"
tell app a
    reopen
    activate
end tell
```

Original Perl script from a [Daring Fireball post](http://daringfireball.net/2009/01/applescripts_targetting_safari_or_webkit) (!).

I've also been changing back and forth between browsers recently, but I just use F11 as a shortcut for a script that opens the main browser.